# How to return void in stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am haveing List of sending orders.It is increased when method name of parameter is same
But It is not working. Because It hasn't **Termination operation**

```
List<SendingOrdres> sendingOrders = new ArrayList<SendingOrdres>();

private void countUpOrResetSendingOrders(String method) {
    sendingOrders.stream()
                 .filter((e) -> {
                     System.out.println("filter:"+e);
                     return e.getMethod().equals(method);
                 })
                 .peek((e) -> System.out.println("peek:"+e)) //For check
                 .map((e)->{
                     int nextNowSendingOrder = e.getNowSendingOrder()+1;
                     if(nextNowSendingOrder > e.getMaxSendingOrder()) {
                         e.setNowSendingOrder(0);
                     }else {
                         e.setNowSendingOrder(nextNowSendingOrder);
                     }
                     return e;
                 });
                 // no Termination operation
}
```

I added Termination operation in upper code. It is working well.

```
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have a question.I don't need to return value. So i want to return **void**.
But If Termination operation hasn't, Stream is not working.
How to return void in stream?

Comment: You are misusing streams. Instead of your last `map` call, you should use `.forEach(...)` and then everything would also work without that fake collector.

Comment: No you didn't. @Zabuzard solved it. You implemented his solution. Be precise.

Comment: Two notes: 1) please do not include the answer in the question. We have questions and answers, to different sections of each post, on this site; 2) if you'd remove `println`, { block } will not be needed (for a single expression) and then `return` must be omitted, as it's implicit in that case.

Comment: That `if` statement *could* be rewritten to `e.setNowSendingOrder(e.getNowSendingOrder() + 1 % e.getMaxSendingOrder() + 1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stream consists of two mandatory (sourcing, terminal) and one optional (intermediate) parts.

Stream:

- is generated with *sourcing* operation (something that creates the `Stream<T>` instance);
- is then optionally continued with one or more, chained *intermediate operation(s)*;
- is finally terminated with *terminal operation*.

`void` can only be considered to be the return type of the *terminal operation* (hence, of its lambda (or method reference) expression) in the stream, because every intermediate operation *has to* return stream, upon which, subsequent intermediate (or terminal) operation would operate.

For example:

```java
List.of(1, 2, 3, 4)
    .stream() //sourcing the stream
    .forEach(System.out::println); //terminating the stream
```

is OK, because `println` just consumes the stream and doesn't have to return another stream.

---

```java
List.of(1, 2, 3, 4)
    .stream() //sourcing the stream
    .filter(System.out::println); //ouch..
```

however, does not compile.

---

Additionally, beware, that Stream API is *lazy*, in Java. Intermediate operations are not effectively evaluated, until the terminal operation is executed.

Comment: Thank you. foreach return void. I was stupid

Comment: Also note that `Stream.of(1,2,3).map(x -> { System.out.println(x); return x; });` will not print anything (the stream is never consumed). This is different from JavaScript for instance.